# How to create a Monthly In/Out Calendar using php and MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, json

Please I need help, I would like to know if there is any way to create a calendar-like grid that will display the In and the Out time of several people. I have created a table that has the following fields:

`code as integer
name as varchar
date as datetime`

Therefore, a record on the table would look like this:

`1234`,`Mark Claus`,`2015-09-01 07:49:00` for an IN hour

`1234`,`Mark Claus`,`2015-09-01 18:03:00` for an OUT hour

Lets say I have 15 people, and 15 records for the month of september, here is the question: 
Is there a way to display this in a grid using php to call the data in the table? Something like:

`Name        In/Out      1       2       3
Mark CLaus     In      7:49    8:04     7:44
               Out     6:03    5:04     5:44
Clara Vann     In      7:49    8:04     7:44
               Out     6:03    5:04     5:44`

The table does not store weekends, but weekends should be displayed in the grid with something like `00:00` , so that it would look like a calendar. I have searched for something similar on the internet but I have not found anything yet.

I would like to avoid using Javascript, or Crystal Reports to do it, is it possible?.

Thanks for the assistance on this.

Comment: How are you defining the difference between a clocking in time and a clocking out time? How will you handle someone not clocking in or out? Are these times coming from a web interface, or are they being taken from a physical card reader?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Clocking in would be the first record on the table for that person, or that code on every date, and Clocking out would be the secord record on the table for that person on each date, I can also add a field that will say IN or OUT depending on the case. If someone does not clock in or does not clock out, the field should display something like `NO TIME`. The times come from a MySQL table.

Comment: What happens if someone clocks in and out multiple times during the day?

Comment: The data on the table is already filtered, so only 2 records will appear for every person each day. If a person only Clocks In, but does not clocks out, the clock IN time will become the clock OUT time as well, and viceversa, that means that 2 records will appear for each person on each date all the time, that unless the person does not shows on certain date, however, if that person has at least one record on the table, the Grid should display that person's Clock IN and OUT time for that date, and fill with 00:00 or blank the rest of the days.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.kimai.org/

Comment: I think that it is beyond my scope, and also I would like to display data from another tables in the future in the same grid as well, so Kimai would not work for me.